# Is there a way to close the error tolerance in chrome?

Tags: html, xpath, browser, scrapy

I use `Scrapy` `xpath` to gather some information.

now I need to locate some element on web pages.

but the brower fix the invalid tags,the structure in DevTool is corrected html.

but in scrapy, request return the origin html,the xpaths which work in DevTool did not work in code any more.

is there a good way to locate the element like in DevTool or close the error tolerance ?

Comment: I don't know about how to fix them in chrome but when this happens I usually print the response in a separate html file and then open it with chrome. This way I can get the exact html that scrapy gets and construct the xpath accordingly.

Comment: maybe you can use scrapy shell command to identify the issue, other then that in most of the cases you should try browser by disabling java script works